# Sum a matrix along an axis given a weight vector using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Does `numpy` provide a built-in way to sum a matrix along an axis given a corresponding weight vector? My goal is to get `z` as output:

```
q = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]])
w = [.3, .4]
z = (q[0] * w[0]) + (q[1] * w[1])

print z
>> [  4.3   8.6  12.9]
```

If not, is there an efficient way to perform this operation taking advantage of broadcasting using `numpy`?

Comment: @Nickil Indeed that does seem to be the answer; I saw that same post and tried `np.dot`, but put the parameters in the wrong order and got an error. Doing `np.dot(w, q)` achieves the desired result. thanks

Comment: What's the point in marking a duplicate when the question already has an accepted answer?  Answers which are better than the so called duplicate.  I'm tempted to switch things, and close the other one as duplicate, linking to this.

Comment: @hpaulj The order I did things was reversed; I marked it as a duplicate and then accepted an answer. My motivation for accepting an answer was to reward the person who took took the time to provide a good answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn `w` into a numpy array with shape `(2, 1)` then you can [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the multiplication over the rows of `q`. One way to do the reshaping would be to index `w` with `np.newaxis` (or equivalently, with `None`):

```
q = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]])
w = np.array([.3, .4])
print(w[:, None] * q).sum(0)
# [  4.3   8.6  12.9]
```

A faster and cleaner way would be to perform [matrix-vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Square_matrix_and_column_vector) using [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
print(w.dot(q))
# [  4.3   8.6  12.9]
```

Comment: Argv.  Why didn't I see the `.dot` there :-)

Comment: Nice use of `np.dot()`.  It's the right way to go for this problem.  +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
>>> np.sum(q * w[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)
array([  4.3,   8.6,  12.9])
```

The trick is to realize that in order to multiply `q` by `w`, we need to insert a new axis into `w`.  Numpy then can then expand along that axis as necessary to match the shape of `q` via normal broadcasting rules.  Once the multiplication has been done, you just need to sum along the correct axis and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: thanks for your perspective/explanation! I will stick with `np.dot` on this one though

Comment: @Ryan -- That's the way that I'd advise you to go too :-).